# How can i achieve this query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

Hello dear friends of SO.

I have this tables:

**PRECIOS**

```
+---------+--------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| priceID | itemID | priceCash | pricePoints | priceDate  |
+---------+--------+-----------+-------------+------------+
|       1 |      1 |     30.00 |          90 | 2012-03-05 |
|       2 |      2 |     40.00 |         120 | 2012-03-05 |
|       6 |      2 |     50.00 |          50 | 2012-03-07 |
|       7 |      2 |     55.00 |          50 | 2012-03-07 |
+---------+--------+-----------+-------------+------------+
```

**ITEMS**

```
+--------+----------------------+-------------+------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| itemID | itemName             | itemWarning | itemUrgent | itemType | itemVipPoints | itemExistence |
+--------+----------------------+-------------+------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
|      1 | Lubricante Orgasmix  |          20 |         10 |        2 |             3 |           300 |
|      2 | Anillo Vibrador      |          50 |         50 |        2 |            50 |           120 |
|      3 | Crema Chantilly      |           5 |         20 |        1 |             0 |           500 |
|      4 | Caribe Cooler        |          10 |          4 |        1 |             0 |           100 |
|      5 | Cacahuates Japoneses |          20 |         10 |        1 |             0 |           400 |
|      6 | Cerveza Sol (lata)   |          12 |        112 |        1 |             0 |           200 |
|      7 | Chocolate derretido  |          20 |         10 |        1 |             0 |           200 |
+--------+----------------------+-------------+------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
```

I need to get a table like this:

- itemType must be '2'
- itemID is required
- itemName is required
- priceCash is required
- itemExistence must be > 0

But, the main problem (for me) is that i need to get the LATEST priceCash for each unique item.

For example, as you can see, itemID = 2 has three prices. I need the table show just the last one (55.00) in this case.

So, in brief: i need to get this:

```
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
| itemID | itemName            | priceCash |
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
|      1 | Lubricante Orgasmix |     30.00 |
|      2 | Anillo Vibrador     |     55.00 |
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
```

But my best result is something like this :(

```
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
| itemID | itemName            | priceCash |
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
|      1 | Lubricante Orgasmix |     30.00 |
|      2 | Anillo Vibrador     |     40.00 |
|      2 | Anillo Vibrador     |     50.00 |
|      2 | Anillo Vibrador     |     55.00 |
+--------+---------------------+-----------+
```

I will tip 5USD on **Apr 15th** vía Paypal to the one who can help me on this one :) Promise.

**SOLUTION**

Provided kindly by **kaj**

```
select it.itemID, it.itemName, p.priceCash
from items it
  inner join precios p on p.itemID = it.itemID
  inner join (select itemID, max(priceID) latestPriceID
              from precios
              group by itemID) latestPrice on latestPrice.itemID = p.itemID and latestPrice.latestPriceID = p.priceID
where it.itemType = 2
  and it.itemExistence > 0
```

*For those who mind, it's about a database for a Motel where they sell all sort of things for sexual pleasure.*

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately my rates start at $100 / hour. This isn't the place to get freelancer help. There are other sites for that.

Comment: Cmon, with column values like `Lubricante Orgasmix` and `Anillo Vibrador`, who could resist?

Comment: I don't care what your rates are @Cfreak. I don't know why you even bother to reply if you have nothing good to say. You should learn something from p.campbell and kaj. If i want to tip, is my f*ckin business.

Comment: @Richard-MX - My rating allows me to moderate. Instead of just requesting your post be closed (which I did) I pointed out that SO isn't a place to get people to do things for you, it's a place to learn by experience. These are things well spelled out in the FAQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you've got duplicate `priceDates` for `itemID` = 2 I assume that the latest price can be determined by using the `priceID`.  So basically you need a query to find the latest price point per item and then to extract the relevant price at that point.

Something like the following should work:

```
select it.itemID, it.itemName, p.priceCash
from items it
  inner join precios p on p.itemID = it.itemID
  inner join (select itemID, max(priceID) latestPriceID
              from precios
              group by itemID) latestPrice on latestPrice.itemID = p.itemID and latestPrice.latestPriceID = p.priceID
where it.itemType = 2
  and it.itemExistence > 0
```

Comment: Wouldn't "LATEST priceCash" be on MAX(priceDate), rather than ID? Agreed, the data in the question is suspect, as we'd ideally want to have time precision to help order properly.

Comment: Not if - as I said in the intro to the query - there are two entries for the same item for the same date - look at rows priceID 6 and 7 - both for itemID = 2 and date 2012-03-07.  Yes normally you'd use the date but here it seems not...

Comment: Kaj, its working :) thanks! Please, provide me email where i can send you the tip i promised. I will do it on April 15th. In 4 days.

Answer (score -1):

```
 select x.itemID, x.itemName, y.priceCash from items x, precios y
 WHERE itemType=2 and x.itemID=y.itemID and x.itemExistence > 0 
 and y.priceID = (select max(t.priceID) from precios t where x.itemID=t.itemID)
 group by x.itemID order by y.priceDate;
```

Comment: down votes should consider adding a comment.